# panic: interface conversion: ast.Expr is *ast.CallExpr, not *ast.Ident, what will be the solution?

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, abstract-syntax-tree, chaincode

I am getting errors while running the chaincode analyzer for the go smart contract.

Target Files:  [fabcar.go]
panic: interface conversion: ast.Expr is *ast.CallExpr, not *ast.Ident

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.pickUpTargetVar(0xc0000d2210, 0x684a30, 0xc0000b8d00)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:466 +0xf3c
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkAssignStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0xc0000b8d40)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:554 +0x26f
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0x686c18, 0xc0000b8d40)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:679 +0x4ac
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0x686d38, 0xc00008f590)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:682 +0x10e
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkRangeStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0xc0000818b0)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:649 +0x6d
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0x687278, 0xc0000818b0)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:696 +0x7cc
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walkStmt(0xc0000d2210, 0x686d38, 0xc00008f5c0)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:682 +0x10e
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*file).storeInfo.func1(0x684cb0, 0xc00008f5f0, 0x685000)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:743 +0xe5
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.walker.Visit(0xc0001c1938, 0x684cb0, 0xc00008f5f0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:1119 +0x3a
go/ast.Walk(0x684348, 0xc0001c1938, 0x684cb0, 0xc00008f5f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/go/ast/walk.go:52 +0x63
go/ast.walkDeclList(0x684348, 0xc0001c1938, 0xc0000ca500, 0xa, 0x10)
    /usr/local/go/src/go/ast/walk.go:38 +0x9e
go/ast.Walk(0x684348, 0xc0001c1938, 0x684c60, 0xc0000c8400)
    /usr/local/go/src/go/ast/walk.go:353 +0x2446
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*file).walk(...)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:1111
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*file).storeInfo(0xc00011a550, 0xc0000d2210)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:737 +0x94
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*file).analyze(0xc00011a550)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:1090 +0x385
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*pkg).analyze(0xc000081310, 0xc00008e960, 0x7fff19af23b9, 0x9)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:115 +0xcc
github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/analyze.(*Analyzer).AnalyzeFiles(0xc0000a7b28, 0xc0000812c0, 0xc0000a7c38, 0x9, 0xc0000a7d98, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00008c510)
    /home/aai/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer@v0.0.0-20200326141029-a98b7983ce34/analyze/analyze.go:63 +0x5e5
main.analyzeFiles(0xc0000812c0, 0xc00008c530, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/bin/chaincode-analyzer-master/ccanalyzer.go:120 +0x1b9
main.main()
    /usr/local/go/bin/chaincode-analyzer-master/ccanalyzer.go:66 +0x517
```

Comment: Cound you share your code?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/chaincode-analyzer/blob/master/analyze/analyze.go this is chaincode analyzer repo

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/chaincode/fabcar/go/fabcar.go and this is the smart contract code